# Is there a way to force the input on Google Sheets to be in the form [m]:ss.00?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am creating a shared spreadsheet of recorded times that are all in the form [m]:ss.00, and I only want inputs of this form to be allowed.  Is there a way to only accept data in this form?  Also, how could I perform calculations using this data (mainly SUM)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to only accept data in this form?

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1), "\d+\:\d{2}\.\d{2}$")
```

[image]

[image]

---

> how could I perform calculations

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(TIMEVALUE("0:"&A1:A2)), "[m]:ss.00"))
```

[image]